# Count unique values in list of sub-lists

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have RDD of the following structure (`RDD[(String,Map[String,List[Product with Serializable]])]`):

This is a sample data:

```
(600,Map(base_data -> List((10:00 01-08-2016,600,111,1,1), (10:15 01-08-2016,615,111,1,5)), additional_data -> List((1,2)))
(601,Map(base_data -> List((10:01 01-08-2016,600,111,1,2), (10:02 01-08-2016,619,111,1,2), (10:01 01-08-2016,600,111,1,4)), additional_data -> List((5,6)))
```

I want to calculate the number of unique values of the 4th fields in sub-lists.
For instance let's take the first entry. The list is `List((10:00 01-08-2016,600,111,1,1), (10:15 01-08-2016,615,111,1,5))`. It contains 2 unique values (`1` and `5`) in the 4th field of sub-lists.

As to the second entry, it also contains 2 unique values (`2` and `4`), because `2` is repeated twice.

The resulting RDD should be of the format `RDD[Map[String,Any]]`.

I tried to solve this task as follows:

```
val result = myRDD.map({
   line => Map(("id",line._1),                        
               ("unique_count",line._2.get("base_data").groupBy(l => l).count(_))))
})
```

However this code does not do what I need. In fact, I don't know how to properly indicate that I want to group by 4th field...

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close to the solution. There is no need to call `groupBy`, but you can access the item of the tuples by index, transform the resulting `List` into a `Set` and then just return the size of the `Set`, which corresponds to the number of unique elements:

```
("unique_count", line._2("base_data").map(bd => bd.productElement(4)).toSet.size)
```

Comment: It says that `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 4`. As far as I understand `bd.productElement(4)` actually accesses the 4th sub-list, but not the 4th field within each list... Strage

Comment: Maybe there should be something like `map(t=>t.map(r=>r.productElement(4))).toSet.size`?

Comment: `line._2("base_data")` returns a `List` of `Product with Serializable`. `.map` iterates on each item of this list. `bd` is a `Product with Serializable` represented by values like `(10:01 01-08-2016,600,111,1,2)`, right? Not sure that we need to apply `map` deeper. BTW, are you sure that all items in the list have same length and structure? (`IndexOutOfBoundsException` makes me think that this is not the case)